# Best practices to handle personal functions in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I have written personal functions in `R` that are not specific to one (or a few) projects.

What are the best practices (in `R`) to put those kind of functions?

Is the best way to do it to have one file that gets sourced at startup? or is there a better (recommended) way to deal with this situation?

Comment: put them in a package and document them.

Comment: Use the .Rprofile file for this purpose, it gets sourced on startup.

Comment: Some people want to close this question, saying it is too opinion-based. I think this is a good enough question to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a package named "utilities" , put utility functions in that package, try to aim for one function per file, and store the package in a source control system (e.g., GIT, SVN ). It will save you time in the long run.

P.S. .Rprofile tends to get accidentally deleted.

Comment: This is the best solution. But don't call it `utilities`, personalize it a little but so when you share it people know where it came from.

Answer (score 3):

If you have many, it would be good to make it into a package that you load each time you start working.

It is probably not a good idea to have a monolithic script with a bunch of functions.  Instead break the file up into several files each of which either has only one function (my preference) or has a group of functions that are logically similar.  That makes it easier to find things when you need to make changes.

Answer (score 2):

Most people use the `.Rprofile` file for this.  Here are two links which talk about this file in some detail.

1. http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html
2. http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/10/sample-rprofile.html

At the top of my .Rprofile file I call `library()` for the various libraries which I normally use.  I also have some personal handy functions which I've come to rely on.  Because this file is sourced on startup, they are available to me every session.

Comment: This also means that your scripts will not work for other people unless they load the required libraries...

Comment: Yes, that's true.  In some sense you could consider putting code in .Rprofile one extreme of formality and rigor, and writing a package and putting it on CRAN the other.  I've done both and think that they both serve different purposes.  From the OP's question I thought that .Rprofile would be a good place to start.

Comment: A package does not have to go on CRAN.

Comment: That's a good point.  The only package I ever created was for distribution on CRAN.  Do you often create packages just for personal usage?

Comment: @Ari RStudio makes it super easy to create another package.  Devtools makes it easy to load a non-CRAN package (`load_all` for local files or `install_github` for Github ones).  `taRifx` and `taRifx.geo` are basically an accumulation of functions I wrote for my own one-off use.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, a package will be the best choice for personal functions. Firstly I put all new functions into a personal package, which I called it My. When I find some functions was similar and are worth to become an independent package, I will create a new package and move them.